# what does that mean "vector augmented to 1"?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, perceptron

I am new to machine learning and statistics (well, I've been learning math in my university but that was about 10-12 years ago)
Could you please explain the meaning of following sentence from 4 page (in a book 5 page) from book here ( https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227612766_An_Empirical_Comparison_of_Machine_Learning_Models_for_Time_Series_Forecasting ):

> The multilayer perceptron (often simply called neural network) is perhaps the most
>   popular network architecture in use today both for classification and regression (Bishop
>   [5]). The MLP is given as follows:
>   N
>    H
>   y ˆ = v0 +
>    j=1
>    X
>    vj g(wj T x′ )
>   (1)
>   **where x′ is the input vector x, augmented with 1, i.e. x′ = (1, xT )T** , wj is the weight
>   vector for j th hidden node, v0 , v1 , . . . , vN H are the weights for the output node, and y ˆ is
>   the network output. The function g represents the hidden node output, and it is given
>   in terms of a squashing function, for example (and that is what we used) the logistic
>   function: g(u) = 1/(1 + exp(−u)). A related model in the econometrics literature is

For instance, we have a vector x = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
How do I transform it to get a x′ vector augmented to 1
x′ = (1, x)

Comment: x' = [1.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5] (might then need to be transposed if you need a column vector)

Comment: thanks, so, if x' = (1, x-transposed) - transposed, according to formula, we have a double transposing and get in result a row vector  
x' = [1.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]

Comment: Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the isomorphism between matrices and systems of equations.  What you have at the moment is a row equivalent to a right-hand-side expression, such as

```
w1 = 0.2*x1 + 0.3*x2 + 0.4*x3 + 0.5*x4
w2 = ...
w3 = ...
w4 = ...
```

When we want to solve the system, we need to augment the matrix.  This requires adding the coefficient of each **w[n]** variable.  They are trivially all ones:

```
1*w1 = 0.2*x1 + 0.3*x2 + 0.4*x3 + 0.5*x4
1*w2 = ...
1*w3 = ...
1*w4 = ...
```

... and that's where we get the augmented matrix.  When we assume the variables by position -- w by row, x by column -- what remains is the coefficients alone, in a nice matrix.